# Why is my DVD drive "/dev/dvd1" instead of "/dev/dvd"?

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu, devices

I rarely use DVD's, so I just noticed that VLC couldn't find the drive (as `/dev/dvd` ). Looking into /dev folder, `/dev/dvd1` and `/dev/dvdrw1` and `/dev/cdrom1` exist. I never had a second dvd drive in there, so my question is:

How did that happen?

What is responsible for assigning those devicenames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say how but the udev rules is assigning those devicenames. In the past, with the Kubuntu: http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3107885.0.

A readme: /etc/udev/rules.d/README

> The files in this directory are read by udev(7) and used when events
>   are performed by the kernel.  The udev daemon watches this directory
>   with inotify so that changes to these files are automatically picked
>   up, for this reason they must be files and not symlinks to another
>   location as in the case in Debian.
>
> Packages do not generally install rules here, this directory is for
>   local rules.  If you want to override behaviour of package-supplied
>   rules, which can be found in /lib/udev/rules.d, you can do one of two
>   things:
>
> 1) Write your own rules in this directory that assign the name,
>       symlinks, permissions, etc. that you want.  Pick a number higher
>       than the rules you want to override, and yours will be used.
>
> 2) Copy the file from /lib/udev/rules.d and edit it here; you
>       should generally only do this if you want to prevent a program
>       from being run.
>
> If the ordering of files in this directory are not important to you,
>   it's recommended that you simply name your files
>   "descriptive-name.rules" such that they are processed AFTER all
>   numbered rules in both this directory and /lib/udev/rules.d and thus
>   override anything set there.

The /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules has the CD and the DVD rules. You could modify it:

> This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_cd_rules
>   program, run by the cd-aliases-generator.rules rules file.
>
> You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
>   line, and set the $GENERATED variable.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info! I think I found out why it's cdrom1 etc - I have a 3g-usb stick with onboard flashdrive which mounts as "CDROM" (in Windows, contains drivers). Somehow this preceded the DVD drive on install.

Comment: Accepted above answer for pointing me at the /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rule file (which caused the problem)

Comment: After modifying the file, you can type `sudo udevadm trigger` to re-create the correct links without rebooting.